# "Interchange" \cup with \bigcup

Tags: macros, symbols, amsmath

I am using `\bigcup` far more often than `\cup` in my code and so I want to change the commands to something like `\bigcup --> \cup` and `\cup --> \smallcup`. Similarly, for `\bigcap` and `\cap` of course. I'm using simply the `amsmath` package.

I have found a way to do this, but I was also wondering what would be the *appropriate* or *tex-friendly* approach to this so that I don't break any other code along in the process.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to do this?

Comment: Why would I _not want_ to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\smallcup\cup 
\let\cup\bigcup
\let\smallcap\cap 
\let\cap\bigcap

\begin{document}
$\smallcup\cup_{i=1}^n \displaystyle \cup_{i=1}^n$

\medskip
$\smallcap\cap_{j=0}^\infty \displaystyle \cap_{j=0}^\infty$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly like this, yes!! So, based on that, why not use ````\let\smallcap\cap```` and ````\renewcommand{\cap}{\bigcap}```` instead? Would that make any difference?

Comment: @jim - I chose my answer mainly because `\let` is shorter than `\renewcommand`. Both approaches should generate the same output.